# T test between price and size

Tags: r, statistics

Im trying to do a t test between 2 variables, price of a building and the size of a building.

Size consists of either "large" or "small"
and Price can be any number (54,2123,325...)

i did this:

```
data$size <- as.factor(data$size)
t.test(data$size ~ data$price, data = data)
```

But i get this error and I cant solve it:

```
Error in t.test.formula(data$size ~ data$price, : 
grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels
```

I am a beginner in R and would appreciate any help
[here you can see the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6H38.png)

Comment: provide a `dput()` of your data

Comment: Try `t.test(price ~ size, data = data)`.

Comment: I get the same error message with that too, sadly

Comment: Other factors come in to play, like materials: kitchen worktop as cheap processed wood or finely polished Italian marble...

Comment: Yes for sure, but for now I just want to test if the average price of large houses are more than the average price of small houses

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post by replacing the content with rubbish.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must reverse the order of the variables that you put in t.test, first comes the numeric variable (price) and then the binary variable (size).

```
size <- c("large","large","small","small","small","small")
price <- c(3536,2239,1982,1769,1769,1769)
data <- data.frame(size, price)

data$size <- as.factor(data$size)
t.test(data$price ~ data$size, data = data)
```

Comment: All you need is `t.test(price ~ size, data = data)`. The whole point of the `data=` argument is to provide the name of the data frame so you don't have to add it to the variable names.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to incorporate @dcarlson's comment?

Answer (score 0):

First, subset the data into small and large:

```
small <- subset(data, size == "small",price, drop = T)
large <- subset(data, size != "small",price, drop = T)
```

Next ensure that your data pass a test of homoscedasticity--are the variances homogenous? We can use `var.test()` for that:

```
var.test(small, large)
```

Finally, depending on whether the p-value came out >0.05 (`var.equal = TRUE`) or <0.05 `(var.equal = FALSE)` we perform a `t.test()`:

```
t.test(small, large, var.equal = TRUE)
```